# Case When with Count inside an ON clause of a JOIN

Tags: sql-server

Inside the JOIN (BB_VENDASDOCUMENTOS VD), I need to choose if VD.ENTRADASAIDA will be 'S' or 'E', what I actually need is, if there is at least one BB_VENDASDOCUMENTOS where ENTRADASAIDA = 'S', use 'S', else 'N'

I've tried to do a CASE WHEN counting the numer of VD.ENTRADASAIDA = 'S', if there is more then 0, It will use 'S', else 'N', but I'm getting an error that and aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause...

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN CENTROCUSTO.DESCRICAO IS NOT NULL THEN CENTROCUSTO.DESCRICAO + '|' ELSE '' END AS [text()]
                                                  FROM BB_PNRACCOUNTINGS ACC1
                                                  JOIN BB_VENDASDOCUMENTOS VD
                                                    ON ( VD.ACCOUNTING = ACC1.HANDLE
                                                                AND  VD.ENTRADASAIDA = CASE WHEN count(case when VD.ENTRADASAIDA = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) > 0 THEN 'S'  ELSE 'E'  END
                                                    AND  VD.PESSOA = ACC1.BB_CLIENTE
                                                    AND ( ( VD.CANCELADO = 'N' ) OR (VD.CANCELADO IS NULL) ) )
                                                  LEFT JOIN BB_CLIENTECC CENTROCUSTO
                                                    ON (CENTROCUSTO.Handle = VD.CENTRODECUSTO)
                                                                  WHERE CENTROCUSTO.DESCRICAO IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Are you attempting to get the count of ENTRADASAIDA='S' for the entire table or for those records where (CANCELADO='N' OR CANCELADO IS NULL)?

Comment: Only for those records that are included inside this JOIN clause, (CANCELADO='N' OR CANCELADO IS NULL) and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to scan the table twice. Once to mark each group with a S or E and then to gather only the records that match the condition. I would do this by joining on a subquery and then join again on the condition. I am not sure the syntax below is 100% correct, however, the basic concept is there.

```
;WITH BB_VENDASDOCUMENTOSCalc AS
(
    SELECT ACCOUNTING,PESSOA,
        ENTRADASAIDACalc = count(case when ENTRADASAIDA = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) > 0 THEN 'S'  ELSE 'E'  END
    FROM 
        BB_VENDASDOCUMENTOS
    WHERE
        (CANCELADO='N' OR CANCELADO IS NULL)
    GROUP BY 
        ACCOUNTING,
        PESSOA
    )
SELECT
 CASE WHEN CENTROCUSTO.DESCRICAO IS NOT NULL THEN CENTROCUSTO.DESCRICAO + '|' ELSE '' END AS [text()]
                                                  FROM BB_PNRACCOUNTINGS ACC1
                                                  JOIN BB_VENDASDOCUMENTOSCalc VD1 ON VD1.ACCOUNTING = ACC1.HANDLE AND VD1.PESSOA = ACC1.BB_CLIENTE
                                                  JOIN BB_VENDASDOCUMENTO VD ON  VD.ACCOUNTING = ACC1.HANDLE AND VD.PESSOA = ACC1.BB_CLIENTE AND VD.ENTRADASAIDA = VD1.ENTRADASAIDACalc
                                                  LEFT JOIN BB_CLIENTECC CENTROCUSTO
                                                    ON (CENTROCUSTO.Handle = VD.CENTRODECUSTO)
                                                                  WHERE CENTROCUSTO.DESCRICAO IS NOT NULL
```